# Enum usage and no match for operator error

Tags: c, enums

I wrote this code but it gives no operator and no match for operator error in loop line.
What is wrong with this code?
Exact Errors:
Line 15:no `operator++(int)' declared for postfix`++', trying prefix operator instead,15 no match for 'operator++' in '++day' 
Code:

```
enum days { Mon=1,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun}; 

int main() 


{ 
 enum days day; 

 const char *dayName[]= {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", 
 "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"}; 

  for(day=Mon;day<=Sun;day++); 
     printf("%2d %11s\n",day,dayName[day]); 

 getch();
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: anyways remember in C array index starts with 0. `<=Sun;` causes bug and will call undefined behavior.

Comment: I made mon=1 if you make mon=1  it keeps goin like tue=2 so on so on;Am i wrong or did you meant diffirent line?

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message. "No match for operator" sounds like a C++ error. Be sure you're compiling your C code as C, not as C++ (use a C compiler, don't name it with a `.cpp` suffix).

Comment: Either start from Mon=0 (that would be also default), or insert  an empty string at `0` index in dayName array as ` *dayName[]= {"", "Monday",`...

Comment: Line 15:no `operator++(int)' declared for postfix `++', trying prefix operator instead,15 no match for 'operator++' in '++day' @KeithThompson

Comment: Your `dayName` array has indices ranging from 0 to 6. Your definition of `enum days` starting from 1 does not (and cannot) affect that.

Comment: @Psybonaut: I meant to include the error message *in the question*. Comments are ephemeral.

Answer (score 3):

This is a complete statement by itself

```
for(day=Mon;day<=Sun;day++);
//                         ^ <== complete statement
//                               anything after this is not part of the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me and print all week day.

Try it here http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

**EDIT :** explain

First a tab start from 0 so I change the enum to start to 0 (default)

Then I rewrite for condition to print all value because in your code you go from 1 to 8 and go outside the tab ( day have to go from 0 to 6).

I add bracket to execute for loop correctly

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  enum days { Mon=0, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun}; //start to 0
  int main() 
  { 
      enum days day; 
      const char *dayName[] = {
            "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
      }; 

      for(day = Mon; day <= Sun; day++){// rewrite condition and add bracket
           printf("%2d %11s\n", day+1, dayName[day]); 
      }

      return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: if you mentions what changes you made, and also add 'why', then ping me I will vote-up.

Comment: Maybe my compiler is broken then

Comment: Add changes and explain :) @GrijeshChauhan

Comment: @Psybonaut, no, your compiler is not broken, Keith already told you, you are just using the wrong compiler. You seem to be compiling C code with a C++ compiler. These are two different languages.